# How do you supply a ClockProvider to Spring v5 (Spring Boot v2)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-validator

What is the proper way to supply your own `ClockProvider` to the `ValidatorFactory` configuration in Spring v5 (Spring Boot v2) so that it's used everywhere the Bean Validations `Validator` is injected?

Use Case: You want to provide a buffer on what it considers "Present", such as described in this [blog post](http://adambien.blog/roller/abien/entry/time_travelling_with_bean_validation) to account for a reasonable amount of clock drift.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution, that also keeps all Spring defaults untouched, is to override method [`postProcessConfiguration()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html#postProcessConfiguration-javax.validation.Configuration-):

```
@Configuration
class TimeConfiguration {

    @Bean
    static Clock clock() {
        return Clock.fixed(
                Instant.ofEpochSecond(1700000000), ZoneOffset.UTC
        );
    }

    @Bean
    static LocalValidatorFactoryBean defaultValidator(Clock clock) {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean() {

            @Override
            protected void postProcessConfiguration(
                javax.validation.Configuration<?> configuration) {
                configuration.clockProvider(() -> clock);
            }
        };
        MessageInterpolatorFactory interpolatorFactory =
            new MessageInterpolatorFactory();
        factoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(interpolatorFactory.getObject());
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring 5 is only runtime compatible with Bean Validation 2.0, which introduced ClockProvider you'd like to use. See next code from Spring [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java#L373-L384). I think there are two ways you can go from this. You can try to use xml configuration for validator and specify clock provider there. It'll look something like this in your validation.xml:

```
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/validation/configuration/validation-configuration-2.0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
    // any other configurations...
    <clock-provider>com.acme.ClockProvider</clock-provider>
</validation-config>
```

Another option, if you don't like xml, would be to try define and use your own `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`.

Also note that maybe for your usecase it'll be useful to use a relatively new feature introduced in Hibernate Validator - temporal validation tolerance, which allow to specify a tolerance for temporal constraints. For more details about it see the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-clock-provider). This tolerance can also be set in xml as well as programatically.

Comment: Do I need to define any other values if I only need to provide my own clock provider implementation? does it inherit from "DefaultValidatorContext" as seen by sources? What about CDI for this? Can I mix spring boot annotations and javax `validation.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [blogpost](https://www.sgmoratilla.com/2019-12-20-testing-code-based-on-time-clock-provider/)

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ClockProvider.class) // to allow tests to overwrite it
public ClockProvider getClockProvider() {
    return () -> Clock.systemDefaultZone();
}
```

Comment: Does absolutely nothing on it's own. This will not be picked up by `Validator` used by Spring.